# *OpenIMSCore* Fail to restart bind9 in the installation step

Tags: dns, virtualbox-networking

I have problem in installing the OpenIMSCore. I use ubuntu in VM Machine and followed the following posts to install OpenIMSCore [Installing an IMS network heart](http://www.ims-way.com/2011/04/open-ims-first-install/). I went through all the first steps and now getting stuck at the step configuring DNS Configuration. I follow instructions:

> **An example of a DNS zone file is present in the installation directory openIMS. Copy it into your DNS configuration directory:
>   ser_ims cp / cfg / open-ims.dnszone / etc / bind /
>
> Edit named.conf.local (still in / etc / bind /) to reflect this new
>   zone (add the following lines): area "open-ims.test"  {type master; 
>   file  "/etc/bind/open-ims.dnszone";};
>
> Check that the named.conf to do well call this file. For this, the
>   following line must be present in the named.conf: include
>   "/etc/bind/named.conf.local"; Add it if it does not.
>
> Edit the file /etc/resolv.conf, delete (or comment on) the existing
>   content and add the following lines: search ims.test  open-domain
>   open-ims.test  nameserver 127.0.0.1
>
> Note: At each reboot of the OS, this file will be overwritten by the
>   Network Manager. So, make a backup of the file (we will use in our
>   script automatically launch servers, we will see at the end of this
>   tutorial): cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.ims
>
> Edit the file / etc / hosts file and add the following lines:
>   127.0.0.1 localhost 
>   127.0.0.1 open ims.test mobicents.open-ims.test ue.open ims.test  presence.ope-n-ims.test icscf.open-ims.test scscf.open-ims.test 
>   pcscf. open-ims.test hss.open-ims.test
>
> Warning: As before, make a backup of this file: cp / etc / hosts
>   /etc/hosts.ims
>
> Restart the DNS server: /etc/init.d/bind9 restart. Check that the
>   configuration change has been taken into account (via dig): open-dig
>   ims.test**

But when I restart the bind9, it show the failed error that I can not restart. Are there anyone have an idea how to get through this step?

*Edit*: Outputs of commands from comments, and `named.conf`:

```
$ pidof named
< no output >
$ sudo named-checkconf
/etc/bind/named.conf.local:9: unknown option 'area'
/etc/bind/named.conf:13: 'options' redefined near 'options'
```

`named.conf.local`:

```
area "open-ims.test" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/open-ims.dnszone";
};
```

`named.conf`:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options"
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
options {
    forward first;
    forwarders { {127.0.1.1;} ; };
};
zone "open-ims.test" IN {
    type master;
    file "etc/bind/open-ims.dnszone";
    notify no;
};
```

Comment: There's no error output here to try and debug this.  `pidof named` - if this returns output then bind9 is running, and we have to stop it first.  `sudo named-checkconf` - if this returns any output you have errors in your bind9 configurations

Comment: Edit you question and copy-paste the named.conf.local file and resolv.conf .ims file

Comment: @ThomasW. hi Thomas, when I try `pidof named`, it returns nothing. And when I try `sudo named-checkconf` it return some errors: **/etc/bind/named.conf.local:9: unknown option 'area'                                                          
/etc/bind/named.conf:13: 'options' redefined near 'options'**

Comment: this is my `named.conf.local`: **area "open-ims.test" 
{type master; 
file 
"/etc/bind/open-ims.dnszone";};**

Comment: and this is my `named.conf` : **include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

options {
 forward first;
 forwarders {
     {127.0.1.1;}  ;
 };
};

zone "open-ims.test" IN {
 type master;
 file "etc/bind/open-ims.dnszone";
 notify no;
};**

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple `bind9` config errors here.  One-by-one we'll fix them.

**`unknown option 'area'`**:

`area` is not a supported `bind9` configuration option.  This is the biggest issue, so remove that entire section in your `named.conf.local`

**`'options' redefined near 'options'`**:

In an Ubuntu setup, the 'options' section is in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`.  Revise that file accordingly, and put your new 'options' section configuration items into there, while commenting out what's there already.  Then remove the 'options' section in /etc/bind/named.conf.

**Uncaught issue: `zone 'open-ims.test' is redefined`**

What the 'area' error above indicates is you tried to create a zone.  You then create the zone in `/etc/bind/named.conf` directly, instead of in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` where you tried to do this earlier.  Take the configuration of the `zone` section you added to `/etc/bind/named.conf` directly, and add it instead to `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` instead.  This should then make it a valid zone.

***Once you've addressed the above errors...***

Now do the following:

```
sudo named-checkconf
```

If this does not error, then proceed to restart the `bind9` service...

```
sudo service bind9 stop
sudo service bind9 start
```